# Add non repeating elements to List in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a `List` and I am trying to add to it elements from another list that are not already `present` in the first `List`.

So if I had 2 Lists :

```
[a, b, 3, c] 
[2, a, b, 4]
```

The output would be:

```
[a, b, 3, c, 2, 4]
```

I am able to get it in reversed order but not in the correct one, here is what I am trying to do:

```
add_to_list(L, [], L).
add_to_list(List, [H|T], [H|Res]) :-
    \+ member(H, List),
    add_to_list(List, T, Res).
add_to_list(List, [H|T], Res):-
    add_to_list(List, T, Res).
```

And when I do the method with the 2 Lists mentioned above the output I get is:

```
[2, 4, a, b, 3, c]
```

I am aware that my ending clause is adding the `L` to the end of the result I get, which is why the order is a mess but how can I do it the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem here is that you should first move to the *end* of the first list before concatenating data.

We can still use the code you have written, but alter it slightly like:

```
atl(_, [], []).
atl(List, [H|T], R) :-
    (  member(H, List)
    -> R = Res
    ;  R = [H|Res]
    ),
    atl(List, T, Res).
```

We here basically made three changes: (a) we renamed `addToList/3` to `atl/3`; we changed `L` to `[]` in the first line; and (c) we used an if-then-else to prevent that the third clause gets triggered even if `H` is not a member of `List` (this was a semantical error in your code).

Now we will obtain for the given input as output:

```
?- atl([a, b, 3, c] , [2, a, b, 4], R).
R = [2, 4] ;
false.
```

So now we can write an `addToList/3` in terms of `atl/3`: we first generate the list of items to append, and next we use `append/3` to append these at the end of the list:

```
addToList(A, B, L) :-
    atl(A, B, R),
    append(A, R, L).
```

Comment: It works but it uses some unknown symbols for me, which look like lambda so I will have to look it up how to use them, but thank you for your answer

Comment: @kataroty: it is an if-then-else: http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node89.html